# Creating a customisable, movable 3D product model in HTML 5

Tags: html, 3d, customization, solidworks

I am not sure what search terms to use to do my own research here so I am hoping somebody else can help me get on the right track.

For my website I want to design a page where a customer can view a 3d model of the product and move it around 360 degrees so they can see every side and angle of the product. I am guessing this would be html5. I will be designing the actual 3d model in solid works I guess.

Also I would like to make this 3d movable product customisable e.g so the user can change colour, add text etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could start with WebGL - this will give you the access to 3D APIs in a web browser. You'll be able to load models, define lighting/materials etc.

Then try to load any mesh in a format that you want to use. This will tell you if WebGL supports your format. There's a chance that you'll need to change your desired format or look for some support library.

The last part is your specific model and behaviour, but it's general for all 3D tools. If you have more specific problem I'm sure somebody here will help you.

Good luck :).